# Converting a CSV string into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For a project, I'm trying to convert my csv file into a dictionary after I have made particular modifications to the file. So,

```
df = pd.read_csv('')
for col in df:
    if col[:10] == 'Warehouse.':
        stripped = col[10:]
        if stripped[:8] != 'timedata':
            print('\n',col)
```

I'm trying to convert the resulting file into a dictionary but am getting stuck. I have tried:

1. To iterate over the file (df) by removing the trailing newline with line.strip("\n"), then split the resultant string with line.split(",") to get a key and value
2. Use the DictReader class before I made the changes in the file, though I keep getting an error saying I can't do this

What would be the best way to conver this modified csv into a dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: 1/ Give some input and output examples in code format. 2/ I do not see direct relation between your question and your code. 3/ What is a csv string?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary also known as a map is a key-value pair data structure, so what exactly are the keys and values you want to have in your dictionary?

I will assume that the key is the row number and the value is the content in that row, but the row itself contains a lot of values in the cells so it's better that the value in the map is an array containing the cells in that row.

to do that let's just recap that in CSV (comma separated values) rows are separated by '\n' which is the new line character, and in each row values are separated by ',' commas hence the name.

```
file_path = "<file_path.csv>"
file = open(file_path,'r') #open the file in read mode


data = file.read() #read the file data
file.close() #close the file

data = data.split('\n') #split the data by new line character to get each line as a list element
data.pop() #remove the last empty row

dict_data = {}
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].split(',') #split each line by comma to get each cell as a list element
    dict_data[i+1] = data[i]

# now data is a list of lists or a 2D array where each element is a list of cells
```

right now you can use the dict_data to give it the row number and the result will be an array where each element contains cell data in the CSV

or you can just use the data 2D array instead of the dict_data, but make sure to use row number + 1 since arrays or lists are zero-based.